# what would be the equivalent this for loop in linq

Tags: linq

I have this for loop that searches a list for specific values and replaces them with new ones.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Data.Count; i++) {

if (Data[i] > 0 && Data[i] <= 10) {Data[i] = 1;}
else if (Data[i] > 10 && Data[i] < 20) {Data[i] = 2;}      
...
}
```

I've been trying to write this function in linq and I know it can be written this way:

```
var Data2 = Data.Where(x=> x > 0 && x <= 10).Select(y=> y=1).ToList();
```

My question is that is there any way to convert this for loop into linq form without the need to declare new lists? I mean a linq form which searches for these values inside the list and when it finds them it replaces them accordingly.

Comment: Why do you want to rewrite it in Linq?

Comment: The reason why I'd like to use Linq is nothing but the code clarity, and actually I want to use it on data mining where I have a large set of noisy data which need to be processed. I'm also curious about the linq solution

Comment: Modifying data in-place is not Linq's strength. Linq methods generally are side-effects free. That is why the .ForEach() method is not a Linq method and is only defined for lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest against doing this with LINQ, anyway:

```
Enumerable.Range(0,Data.Count)
          .ForEach(x=>{ 
              if (Data[x] > 0 && Data[x] <= 10) {Data[x] = 1;}
              else if (Data[x] > 10 && Data[i] < 20) {Data[x] = 2;} 
          });
```

this way you don't have to declare a second list, but the code looks less readeable than your original one.

Comment: Why don't just Data.ForEach(...); ?

Comment: Because you can't change an element value inside the foreach call. This List<int> l = new List<int> { 1, 1, 1 };l.ForEach(x => x=2);Console.WriteLine(l[1]); prints 1, not 2 as you are suggesting

Comment: Yea, it's because the index is needed.

Comment: Just a side note: ForEach is not present in plain LINQ, it's a [MoreLinq extension](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/ForEach.cs?r=f4c39a771d712a568467eaa31840cc22e07a5ed0)

Answer (score 2):

The exact equivalent would be:

```
Data
  .Select((e,i) => new { Element = e, Index = i })
  .Where(ei => ei.Element > 0 && ei.Element < 20)
  .ToList()
  .ForEach(ei => Data[ei.Index] = (ei.Element <= 10) ? 1 : 2);
```

or second possibility: look at [Save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18427812/what-would-be-the-equivalent-this-for-loop-in-linq/18427840#18427840)'s answer.

However it's still creating a List in-between (`ForEach` comes only for `List<T>`). It's not very readable, better to use non-mutable approach and just generate new list basing on given criteria.

Answer (score 1):

A lot simpler than the other solutions:

```
Data = Data.Select(d => (d / 10) + 1)
```

If you want a top limit, just use `Math.Min((d / 10) + 1, topLimit)` instead.

Comment: You don't know whether the list doesn't contain elements greater than 20 that weren't to be changed.

Comment: @BartoszKP I'm assuming for greater than 20 he has a maximum value to fall back to. If not, then sure, the other answers are better.

Comment: Note that, as stated in the question, 10 maps to 1 but 20 doesn't map to 2. Of course, that might be an error in the question.

Comment: @MatthewStrawbridge Whoops, I thought it was a `<=` :P

Answer (score 1):

Modifying data in-place is not Linq's strength. Linq methods generally are side-effects free. That is why the .ForEach() method is not a Linq method and is only defined for lists.

However there is nothing preventing you from making Linq functions with side-effects.
So I would not recommend this solution, but you can do anything within a select statement, even modifying the underlying list. There is also a select overload that uses the element and its index as parameters ( Select( (element,index) => ... ).

So you can do anything with select you can do in a for loop. But I would recommend the for loop for readability.

```
data.Select((d,i)=>
    {if (d > 0 && d <= 10) data[i]=1 else if (d>10 && d<20 data[i]=2;})
    .All(d=>true); // <-- note that you do need some way to consume the IEnumerable
                   // in order to execute the .Select(). You can use ToList(), Count(), ..
```